# Going back in time

Tags: creative-writing, characters, fantasy, world-building, protagonist

If i were to have a character go back in time, could there be a rule for having only one world exist? So if she goes back in time, the other world would be destroyed? Could that potentially happen, so that there's no alternate universe where her friends can never see her again, but her friends slowly regain their memories about what happened before she went back in time?
If that makes no sense, let me know, i know it sounds confusing, but can someone please help me with this?

Comment: sounds like flash S2 and 3, also seems like a worldbuilding question more than writing.

Comment: @Ceramicmrno0b I don't think this would be suitable for WorldBuilding.SE, they would probably shoot back something like, "It's your world, you can have whatever rule you like, that's not something we can decide that for you".

Comment: @Serafina Having said that, I'm afraid this isn't something *we* can decide for you, either. We can help you with the technical details of writing your story, but we can't come up with important plot points or major aspects of your world for you. As long as your time-travelling rules are internally consistent, you can set them up whichever way works best for you story.

Comment: Sounds like you want to use a "Bootstrap Paradox" which occurs where the events of the past take into account that time travel happened.   The idea is that you are inspired to make a chair based on a photograph of one you saw.   When you finish making the chair, you take a picture of it identical to the one you saw.   Somehow, time travel takes your picture back to point before you were inspired and leaves the picture where you found it when you discovered it.  Thus you find the pic, you make the chair, you take the pic.

Comment: @Serafina  you might want to check out this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_travel_in_fiction  -  and especially: Gleick, James (2016). Time Travel: A History. Pantheon. ISBN 978-0307908797.